# PHP functions generate discordant results in WP frontend vs database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function that generates a `chapter_id`:

```
add_action('user_register', 'fetch_chapter');
function fetch_chapter_id(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = \'chapter_name\' AND user_id = '. $current_user->ID .' LIMIT 1');
    if ($result == 'Peregrine') {
        $chapter_id = 'PG';
    }elseif ($result == 'Barbary') {
        $chapter_id = 'BB';
    }elseif ($result == 'Prairie') {
        $chapter_id = 'PR';
    }

        return $chapter_id;
}
add_shortcode('chapter_id', 'fetch_chapter_id');
```

Then this uses the chapter_id to generate a `member_id`:

```
add_action('user_register', 'generate_member_id');
function generate_member_id($user_id){

    // If no user_id is passed in, use the current user id
    if (!$user_id) $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $unique_id = 1000 + $user_id;
    $chapter_id = fetch_chapter_id();
    $member_id = "FAL-" . $chapter_id . "-" . $unique_id;
    
    return $member_id;
}
add_shortcode('member_id', 'generate_member_id');
```

Finally, this adds the member_id to a WP database:

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users" );
if( $users ) {
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'member_id', generate_member_id($user->ID) );
    }
}
```

The output of the 1st and 2nd snippets are accurate and I can check that in the frontend using the `[chapter_id]` and `[member_id]` shortcodes.

But the result of the 3rd snippet is incorrect and always contains the admin chapter_id (I am logged in as admin).

So I have a discrepancy between the value displayed in the frontend and the value saved in the database. If I create a new user, the member_id in the frontend is correct, but the member_id saved in the database incorrectly contains the chapter_id of the admin.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason the shortcodes work is because the person viewing the page is both the "member" user *and* the current user.
But when you are updating the database, you are the current user and *not* the "member" user - however the code is still using the current users value (i.e. your data) to update the member user data.

You can change your `user_register` function to accept the user_id as a parameter. Then:

- if a user id is passed in (e.g. during the user registration from the `add_action`), that will be the member users id, so you select the chapter for that user.
- if no user id is passed in (e.g. when using the shortcode), then the current users id will be used.

This is what the `fetch_chapter_id` function should look like now - I've just added the user_id as a parameter (comment **#1** in the code) and changed the code that sets this value (comment **#2**):

```
// #1. Set up user_id as a parameter
function fetch_chapter_id($user_id=""){

    // #2. If no user_id is passed in, use the current user id
   if (!$user_id){
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    }

    // the rest of the function stays the same
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = \'chapter_name\' AND user_id = '. $user_id .' LIMIT 1');
    if ($result == 'Peregrine') {
        $chapter_id = 'PG';
    }elseif ($result == 'Barbary') {
        $chapter_id = 'BB';
    }elseif ($result == 'Prairie') {
        $chapter_id = 'PR';
    }

        return $chapter_id;
}
```

Now, you just need to also pass the user_id into the function in your **`generate_member_id`** function see comment **#3** in the coe:

```
function generate_member_id($user_id){  
    // If no user_id is passed in, use the current user id
    if (!$user_id) $user_id = get_current_user_id();    
    $unique_id = 1000 + $user_id;

    // #3. pass in the member's user id so you get the chapter for the correct user
    $chapter_id = fetch_chapter_id($user_id);

    $member_id = "FAL-" . $chapter_id . "-" . $unique_id;
    
    return $member_id;
}
```